# Batch file open CMD with myapp.exe file ready to be executed

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exe

I want to create a batch file that opens the CMD places myapp.exe file on the prompt line (not execute) and wait for the user to add parameter string. I have tried the following, but it executes the .exe file when I double click on the batch file.

```
cmd /k "C:\myapp.exe"
```

Comment: Try to use Set/p or choice command

Comment: It should be `/k` not `\k`

Answer (score 0):

Using `SET /P` command will come close. And would be far easier than stuffing the keyboard buffer.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P PARAMS="Enter the parameter(s) with which to run C:\myapp.exe: "
REM If nothing is entered, do not run the program.
IF NOT "%PARAMS%" == "" ("C:\myapp.exe" %PARAMS%)
EXIT /B
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you wanted, *(just change your executable string  on line `2` as needed)*:

```sh
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "Executable=C:\myapp.exe"
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K "Set "args=" & Set /P "=%Executable% " 0< NUL & Set /P "args=" & For /F Tokens^=*^ EOL^= %%G In ('Call Set /P "=%%args%%" 0^< NUL') Do @If "%%G" == "%%args%%" ("%Executable%") Else "%Executable%" %%G"
```

*I love wasting tea breaks :)*